# Some mutation stayed "pending" during update query

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, sequelize.js, redux-toolkit

When  i use a mutation to update my "post", sometime the api call is blocked and the status is pending on "redux devtools".

The first call is ok but if i push my button too many times, data is not updated on database.

Somebody can help me ?

```
updatePost: build.mutation<void, Pick<Post, 'id'> & Partial<Post>>({
      query: ({ id, ...patch }) => ({
        url: `posts/${id}`,
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: patch,      }),     
            async onCacheEntryAdded(
        arg,
        {
          dispatch,
          getState,
          extra,
          requestId,
          cacheEntryRemoved,
          cacheDataLoaded,
          getCacheEntry,
        }
      ) {
        console.log(arg)
        console.log("Mutation = ")
        console.log(getState().api.mutations)
      },
          invalidatesTags: [{ type: 'Post', id: 'LIST' }],
```

Backoffice :

```
exports.updatelike = (req) => {
  try {
    console.log("UPDATELIKE");
    const d = new Date(Date.now());
    console.log(d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds());
    console.log(req.params.id);
    var values = {
      likes: req.body.likes,
      userslike: req.body.userslike,
      dislikes: req.body.dislikes,
      usersdislike: req.body.usersdislike,
    };
    var selector = { where: { id: req.params.id } };

    Post.update(values, selector)
      .then(
        function (success) {
          console.log("SUCCESS");
          console.log(success);
        },
        function (err) {
          console.log("ERROR");
          console.log(err);
        }
      )
      .finally(function () {
        console.log("FINALLY");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(">> Error while Update one post : ", err);
      });
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
  }
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDhhg.png)

Comment: It seems like these network requests just hang in some way. Do they resolve in your network tab?

Comment: i think that i forget to send result after update. res.send is ok.